# spring multiple property file

Tags: spring

I have a spring project. There are two property files. one property file is config in dbConfig.xml and I cannot change it. I have my own appConfig.xml

I have the following in it

```
<util:properties id="configProps" location="classpath:spring/config.properties" />

<bean id="createDummyDataTask" class="com.merc.spring.CreateDummyData" scope="step">
    <property name="srcFolder" value="${configProps.srcDir}"/>
</bean>
```

using either srcDir or configProps.srcDir does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`${}` works only for property files loaded by the context:propertyplaceholder.  If you are using spring 3.0 you can use `#{}` which is processed as a Spel (spring expression language).  The following should work.

```
<util:properties id="configProps" location="classpath:spring/config.properties" />

<bean id="createDummyDataTask" class="com.merc.spring.CreateDummyData" scope="step">
    <property name="srcFolder" value="#{configProps.srcDir}"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here how we resolved it

**Context.xml**

```
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">

        <import resource="Settings.xml"/>
        <import resource="Database.xml"/>   

    </beans>
```

**Settings.xml**

In the list many property file could be added

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">

                <bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
                <property name="locations">
                    <list>
                        <value>db.properties</value>
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>

        </beans>
```

Sample bean for processing `db.properties` file

**Database.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">

        <!-- the transaction manager -->
        <bean id="dstxnManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="appDataSource"/>
        </bean>

        <!-- the DataSource (parameterized for configuration via a PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer) -->
        <bean id="appDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" lazy-init="false">
            <property name="driverClass"              value="${driverClass}" />
            <property name="jdbcUrl"                  value="${jdbcUrl}" />
            <property name="user"                     value="${username}" />
            <property name="password"                 value="${password}" />
        </bean> 

        <!-- DB connection factory -->
        <bean id="storageDaoFactory" class="com.dao.StorageDAOFactory">
             <constructor-arg><ref bean="dstxnManager"/></constructor-arg>
        </bean>

    </beans>
```